# PHP preg_replace between string and quotes

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I have a config file with the following content in it;

```
[settings]
; absolute path to the temp dir. If empty the default system tmp directory will be used
temp_path = ""

; if set to true: detects if the contents are UTF-8 encoded and if not encodes them
; if set to false do nothing
encode_to_UTF8 = "false"

; default document language
language = "en-US"

; default paper size
paper_size = "A4"

[license]
; license code
code = "8cf34efe0b57013668df0dbcdf8c82a9"
```

I need to replace the key between the **code = "*"** to something else, how can I do this with preg_replace()? The config file contains more options so I only need to replace the key between

```
code = "*replace me*"
```

It should be something like this;

```
$licenseKey = 'newLicenseKey';
$configFileContent = file_get_contents(configFile.ini);
$configFileContent = preg_replace('/(code = ")(.*)(")/', $licenseKey, $configFileContent);
```

But this replaces the whole line with only the new licenseKey.

How can i do this?

Comment: can you paste example output? and what you tried so far?

Comment: I updated my post above.

Comment: that, to me, looks like an ini file. PHP has [a `parse_ini_file` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php), that returns an array. Use that, edit what needs editing and use that data (to write a new ini file, or whatever)

Answer (score 7):

You need something called [PCRE Lookaround Assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php), more specifically: positive lookahead `(?=suffix)` and lookbehind `(?<=prefix)`. This means you can match prefixes and suffixes without capturing them, so they will not be lost during a regex match&replace.

Your code, using those:

```
$licenseKey = 'newLicenseKey';
$configFileContent = file_get_contents(configFile.ini);
$configFileContent = preg_replace('/(?<=code = ")(.*)(?=")/', $licenseKey, $configFileContent);
```

Comment: I would probably add some excludes to the check to make sure the script isn't vulnerable to attack. Should exclude " and linebreaks at the least.

Comment: nit-pick: _PREG assertions_ is a odd term: PREG is the prefix for all PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) functions. What you're referring to is lookaround assertions

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, I'd tackle this issue by treating the file as what it is *an INI file*.

1. Parse the file
2. Update values that need to change
3. overwrite the file or do something else (depending on your needs)

I'll assume you want to update the file, so in this example, I'll overwrite it:

```
$iniData = parse_ini_file('configFile.ini', true);//quote the filename
foreach ($iniData as $section => $params) {
    if (isset($params['code'])) {
        $params['code'] = $newCode;
        $iniData[$section] = $params;//update section
    }
}
//write to new file
$lines = [];//array of lines
foreach ($iniData as $section => $params) {
    $lines[] = sprintf('[%s]', $section);
    foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
        $lines[] = sprintf('%s = "%s");
    }
}
file_put_contents('configFile.ini', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

You can combine both loops quite easily, to simplify the code:

```
$lines = [];
foreach ($iniData as $section => $params) {
    if (isset($params['code'])) {
        $params['code'] = $newCode;
    }
    $lines[] = sprintf('[%s]', $section);
    foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
        $lines[] = sprintf('%s = "%s");
    }
}
```

Comment: While my answer is the answer to what the OP wants, this is the answer to what the OP _needs_. Therefore: +1.

Comment: Thanks, this is even a better solution!.

Comment: @Lumix1991: Happy to help. Please, [consider accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), depending on which answer best answered your question/was most useful or provides the best information for future reference (ie other people who might have the same question)